# Issue with Spring Framework static resource set up

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, model-view-controller

I have configured my spring project to cater to static resources using below settings in XML file:

```
<annotation-driven />
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

But when I try to access the static content directly, say using below URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/main/resources/css/app.css
```

Instead of showing up the static CSS content in the browser, the request is going to the following method in Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{countryID}/{stateId}/{cityId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String city(@PathVariable("countryID") String countryID, @PathVariable("stateId") String stateId, @PathVariable("cityId") String cityId, Locale locale, Model model) {
        System.out.println("input "+stateId);
        System.out.println("input "+countryID);
        System.out.println("input "+cityId);
        model.addAttribute("serverTime", "");
        return "home";
    }
```

Once the request leads to this method instead of showing up the staic CSS file, I see the JSP page returned by return call "home".

I have checked and rechecked but dont really sight any issue with set up.
Please have a look and let me what might be going wrong here.

Below is the Main Controller that my application is using.

```
import java.util.Locale;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String country(Locale locale, Model model) {
        System.out.println("nothing but home page");
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{countryID}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String country(@PathVariable("countryID") String countryID, Locale locale, Model model) {
        System.out.println("input country "+countryID);
        return "home";
    }   

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{countryID}/{stateId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String state(@PathVariable("countryID") String countryID, @PathVariable("stateId") String stateId, Locale locale, Model model) {
        System.out.println("input "+stateId);
        System.out.println("input "+countryID);
        model.addAttribute("serverTime", "");
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{countryID}/{stateId}/{cityId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String city(@PathVariable("countryID") String countryID, @PathVariable("stateId") String stateId, @PathVariable("cityId") String cityId, Locale locale, Model model) {
        System.out.println("input "+stateId);
        System.out.println("input "+countryID);
        System.out.println("input "+cityId);
        model.addAttribute("serverTime", "");
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{countryID}/{stateId}/{cityId}/{destId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String dest(@PathVariable("countryID") String countryID, @PathVariable("stateId") String stateId, @PathVariable("cityId") String cityId, @PathVariable("destId") String destId, Locale locale, Model model) {
        System.out.println("input "+stateId);
        System.out.println("input "+countryID);
        System.out.println("input "+cityId);
        System.out.println("input "+destId);
        model.addAttribute("serverTime", "");

        return "home";
    }
}
```

And below is the application XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!--    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver" />

    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <beans:property name="definitions">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>/WEB-INF/views.xml</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean> -->

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.travel.main" />



</beans:beans>
```

Comment: Have you tried switching the order of your tags to

   <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
   <annotation-driven /> 

?

Comment: Just tired it but doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, your @RequestMapping in the controler has precedence over the resource-mapping. To change this, you have to do two things:

Add the attribute `order="0"` to your resources-tag.

Change the order of your tags to:

```
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" order="0" />
<annotation-driven />
```

Then it should work.

Comment: hey Florian. i made the change and its working fine now. You brought an end to my 2 week long struggle. thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

It seems `http://localhost:8080/main/resources/css/app.css` is mapped to `/{countryID}/{stateId}/{cityId}`:

- countryId=resources
- stateId=css
- cityId=app.css

It seems the resources are only mapped when there is no Controller that matches the URL, so you can try to add to that controller a different path: You can change `@RequestMapping("/")` to `@RequestMapping("/mainController")` or add something like `/city/` in the matcher of the `city` method: `city/{countryID}/{stateId}/{cityId}`.

Comment: thanks for ur reply Pablo. Yes if I add city or any other string it would work. But I am working on project to move an existing PHP project to spring and I need to keep the URL format same. {countryID}/{stateId}/{cityId} all three needs to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try the following options:

1. Remove `@RequestMapping("/")` from the `MainController`.
2. Add a View Resolver to your Spring configuration. For instance, `InternalResourceViewResolver`.
3. Take a look at the [Spring doc](http://spring.io/blog/2014/07/24/spring-framework-4-1-handling-static-web-resources).
4. Move the resources directory to the same level as views. That is,/WEB-INF/views and /WEB-INF/resources.

I hope that helps!